# NavTabs : Call method when TabPane clicked

Tags: gwtbootstrap3

I'm pretty new to GwtBootstrap3 so don't know much about JavaScript functions but I'm using navtabs with DataGrids in the tabs and looking for a way to call a data loading method whenever the tab is selected as I don't want to call all RPC methods at once when the NavTabs is initialized.

Here's my code:

```
        <b:NavTabs>
            <b:TabListItem active="true" dataTarget="#tab1" text="Profile" />
            <b:TabListItem dataTarget="#tab2" text="Bundles" />
        </b:NavTabs>

        <b:TabContent>
            <b:TabPane active="true" b:id="tab1">
                <b:Column addStyleNames="{style.spacing}" size="MD_12">
                    <b:Panel>
                        <b:PanelBody ui:field="profile">
                        </b:PanelBody>
                    </b:Panel>
                </b:Column>
            </b:TabPane>

            <b:TabPane b:id="tab2">
                <b:Column addStyleNames="{style.spacing}" size="MD_12">
                    <b:Panel>
                        <b:PanelBody ui:field="bundles">
                        </b:PanelBody>
                    </b:Panel>
                </b:Column>
            </b:TabPane>
```

and for the tabs:

```
<b:Well addStyleNames="{style.center-panel}">
    <gwt:DataGrid bordered="true" condensed="true" striped="true"
        hover="true" height="100%" width="100%" ui:field="profileGrid" />
</b:Well>
```

I've tried using AttachHandler on the tabs which doesn't load the data.

Is there any way to call an RPC method (loadBundlesData()) whenever the Bundles tab is selected and not having to load that in advance with the NavTabs?
Any help/comments appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add a click handler to your `TabListItem`:

in your ui.xml:

```
<b:NavTabs>
    <b:TabListItem active="true" dataTarget="#tab1" text="Profile" />
    <b:TabListItem ui:field="bundleListItem" dataTarget="#tab2" text="Bundles" />
</b:NavTabs>
```

in your .java:

```
@UiHandler("bundleListItem")
public void onClickBundleListItem(ClickEvent event){
    //do the job here
}
```

or:

```
bundleListItem.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        // do the job
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.